# ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(FatalErrorException))

Tags: php, cakephp

```
Php Cake Error on 7.3.33

PHP 7.3.33 (cli) (built: Nov 16 2021 11:18:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.33, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies





Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php:174
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(92): ExceptionRenderer->_getController(Object(FatalErrorException))
#1 /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(126): ExceptionRenderer->__construct(Object(FatalErrorException))
#2 /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(284): ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(FatalErrorException))
#3 /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(213): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(64, 'Cannot use 'Obj...', '/var/www/html/m...', 30)
#4 /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(970): ErrorHandler::handleError(64, 'Cannot use 'Obj...', '/var/www/html/m...', 30, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(943): App::_checkFatalError()
#6 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#7 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mobileapp_api/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php on line 174
```

Comment: Question is????

Comment: Yes sir that is my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems Controller class is not found. Check if you see Controller.php into

```
vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php
```

If not, try to delete vendor folder and run `composer install` again